# Finding min and max using SD

Tags: standard-deviation, extreme-value

Given mean and standard deviation, is there any way to find minimum and maximum in a collection of 50 numbers?

Comment: In general no. If you have 50 random variables, then the maximum is itself a random variable, and you can talk about the *distribution* of that random variable. For example if the 50 numbers were independent draws from some normal distribution, then you can calculate the probability distribution for the maximum value of the set of 50. The simplest way to compute the CDF would almost certainly be numerical simulation.

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting question here is what kind of *restrictions* knowing the mean and standard deviation imposes on the min and max.

Comment: Perhaps the even more interesting question is what the heck is the OP actually trying to ask?  The question statement is hardly a paragon of clarity.

Comment: I now think this is probably a duplicate -- I just have to find the right posts. (I may delete my answer once I find a suitable duplicate or duplciates)

Answer (score 3):

No. Two different samples with different min and max values can have the same mean and standard deviation.

Answer (score 2):

If all you know is the mean and standard deviation, you can at best try to bound them but the bounds are quite wide.

The max or min can be anywhere between $1/\sqrt{n}$ and $(\sqrt{n}-1)$ standard deviations from the mean.

However, for even $n$, the range (max-min) cannot be less than $2s_n$ (the version of standard deviation that has an $n$ denominator rather than $n-1$), which is $2\sqrt{1-\frac{_{1}}{^n}}s$, and can be as much as $\sqrt{2n}s_n=\sqrt{2(n-1)}s$ (for odd $n$ the bounds are slightly different but I won't labor the point).

So for example if the sample size, $n$ was 25, and the mean was 100 and the sd was 15, then the maximum might be anywhere between $100+15/5 = 103$ and $100+15\times 4=160$.

If $n$ was instead 100, then those bounds move to 101.5 and 235.